# What is compiler option string for use clang?

Tags: c++, c, macos, cmake

I am trying to figure out what is the compiler option string for "use clang compiler". Something similar to `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu++11` that I can pass it to `target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE <compilation_parameter>)`.

As a reference, my VSCode's CMake uses the below compiler kit and this is what I essentially want to specify.

```
  {
    "name": "Clang 14.0.0 x86_64-apple-darwin22.2.0",
    "compilers": {
      "C": "/usr/bin/clang",
      "CXX": "/usr/bin/clang++"
    }
  },
```

Comment: there's no compiler option for picking a compiler... because by the time you're specifying options you're already picked the compiler... this question doesn't actually make any sense. unless I'm missing something and misunderstood the question.